# C, using argv[] for command line arguments

Tags: c, file, argv

I'm having trouble with this program, it's working perfectly when I use stdin but when I modify it to get characters from the command line it doesn't. I know I'm doing something wrong but don't know what, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Description and code:

```
/* Program prints the date in this form: September 13, 2010
    allow the user to  enter date in either 9-13-2010 or 9/13/2010  
    format, otherwise print 'error'  */

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

char *month(int m)
{
    char *months[]={"January","February","March","April","May",
                "June", "July","August","September","October",
                "November","December"};
    return months[m-1];
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{

    int m=0,d=0,y=0;

    FILE *fp;

    if((fp=fopen(argv[1],"rb")) == NULL)
    {
        fprintf(stderr,"Couldn't open the file. ");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }


    printf("Type a date (mm-dd-yyyy) or (mm/dd/yyyy): \n");

    if(fscanf(fp,"%d%*[/-]%d%*[/-]%d",&m,&d,&y) != 3)  //store characters in variables
        {
            fprintf(stderr, "Not properly formatted.");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }

    printf("%s %2d, %4d",month(m),d,y);

    return 0;
}
```

Input:

```
01/30/1990
```

Output:

```
Couldn't open the file.
```

Comment: How are you invoking the compiled program?

Comment: Im using codeblocks ide, I typed 01/30/1990 in the Program argument windows, I also have used gcc to run it and it says "The system cannot accept the date you entered". "A required priviledge is not held by the client".

Comment: `fopen("01/30/1999","rb")` will try to open a file with the path `01/30/1999`. Obviously, no such file exists.

Comment: `argv[1]` has undefined behaviour unless you previously ascertain that `argc` is at least two.

Comment: How can I get the input from the command line and then extract the information to put them into variables? I don't know really if my approach of using files is even the right way to do it.

Comment: Don't use `fscanf` (file-`scanf`) on `fp`, but use `sscanf` (string-`scanf`) on `argv[1]`.

Comment: Instead of `fprintf(stderr,"Couldn't open the file. ");` (which produces a nearly useless error message), try `perror( argv[1])`, which will tell you exactly what the problem is.

Comment: You could call the program's "stdin"-version like this:`echo "01/01/01" | program` :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I modified your program to fix the issue you were having (and to fix some *undefined behaviour*, or "UB" for short), but only that:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

const char *month(int m) {
    const char const *months[] = {
        "January", "February", "March", "April",
        "May", "June", "July", "August",
        "September", "October", "November", "December",
    };

    if (1 <= m && m <= 12) {
        return months[m - 1];
    } else {
        return NULL;
    }
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int m = 0, d = 0, y = 0;

    if (argc == 2) {
        if (sscanf(argv[1], "%d%*[/-]%d%*[/-]%d", &m, &d, &y) != 3) {
            fprintf(stderr, "Not properly formatted.");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }

        printf("%s %2d, %4d", month(m), d, y);
    } else {
        fprintf(stderr, "Please provide one date argument to the program, formatted as mm-dd-yyyy or mm/dd/yyyy\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

What changed?

- I changed the return type of `month()`. Its array is backed by string literals, so you shouldn't be able to accidentally modify them in future versions of your program, which would cause UB.
- I introduced a range check in `month()`. It now returns a null pointer when when `m` is too small (e.g. `0/0/0`) or too large (e.g. `25/09/2016`), preventing some UB.
- I removed all code regarding opening files. You don't want to open a file based on a file name in `argv`, you just want to use `argv[1]` as a string.
- I introduced a check to see whether `argv[1]` exists. `argc` contains the size of `argv`, and if it's `2`, `argv` contains the program's name and its first command line argument.
- Again, you don't want to read from a file, but parse a command line argument as a string, so I changed `fscanf` to `sscanf`.

Answer (score 0):

Here we have a generic solution. The date can be passed via file (fscanf), via command line (sscanf) or typed (scanf).

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

char* month(int m)
{
    char* months[] = { "January", "February", "March", "April", "May",
        "June", "July", "August", "September", "October",
        "November", "December" };
    return months[m - 1];
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    int m = 0, d = 0, y = 0;

    FILE* fp;

    int wrongFormat = 0;

    if (argc > 1) 
    {
        if  ((fp = fopen(argv[1], "rb")) == NULL) 
        {
            if (sscanf(argv[1], "%d%*[/-]%d%*[/-]%d", &m, &d, &y) != 3) 
                wrongFormat = 1;
        }
        else 
        {
            if (fscanf(fp, "%d%*[/-]%d%*[/-]%d", &m, &d, &y) != 3)
                wrongFormat = 1;
        }
    }
    else 
    {
        printf("Type a date (mm-dd-yyyy) or (mm/dd/yyyy): \n");
        if (scanf("%d%*[/-]%d%*[/-]%d", &m, &d, &y) != 3)
            wrongFormat = 1;
    }

    if (wrongFormat) 
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Not properly formatted.");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    printf("%s %2d, %4d\n", month(m), d, y);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: OP's comment shows that this isn't what they wanted: "How can I get the input from the command line and then extract the information to put them into variables?"

Comment: m, d and y are variables.

Comment: That's not the point. OP wants to read the input *from the command line*, instead of *from a file specified on the command line*.

Comment: OK, @Rhymoid. Now it will work with command line as well. Thanks for your comment and +1 for your answer that is also correct!